# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (threads)

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I write my debug information to a file using a separate thread.  During startup, I like to backup any previous file.  Unfortunately, it seems the OS hangs onto the file handle for an indeterminate amount of time so when I try to write to the file, it fails.

I am using C#, .Net framework 3.5 on Windows XP.  (Vista and Win7 have the same problem).

Here is the code that distills the problem, where `t` will throw a System.IO.IOException: "The process cannot access the file 'C:\deleteMe.txt' because it is being used by another process."

```
public class WriteToFile {

    static void Main(){
        String filename=@"C:\deleteMe.txt";
        String filenameBackup = @"C:\deleteMe (backup).txt";
        String value = "this is a test value";

        //MAKE FILE
        fillFile(filename, value);


        //MAKE A THREAD TO WRITE TO FILE, WHEN READY
        Semaphore readyToWrite=new Semaphore(1, 1);
        var t=new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(delegate(){
                readyToWrite.WaitOne();
                WriteToFile.fillFile(filename, value);
            })
        );
        t.Priority=ThreadPriority.Highest;
        t.Start();


        //BACKUP FILE 
        if (File.Exists(filename)) {
            File.Delete(filenameBackup);
            File.Copy(filename, filenameBackup);
            File.Delete(filename);
        }//endif

        //SIGNAL THREAD TO WRITE TO FILE
        readyToWrite.Release();
    }//method


    public static void fillFile(String filename, String value) {
        try {
            StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(filename);
            using (w) {
                w.Write(value);
                w.Flush();
            }//using
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Can not write to file", e);
        }//try
    }//method


}//class
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you properly closing or disposing the file when you write to it?

Comment: @Steven: that is all in the code provided. The answer is Yes.

Comment: @Henk: It turns out that it's possible to scroll down! :-) Ok, the declaration of `w` prior to the `using` is a bit odd, but should be harmless, as should the call to `Flush`. As far as I can tell, there is no reason why the file shouldn't immediately be available. Perhaps some other process is getting involved, such as an antivirus scanner.

Comment: @Steven: Scroll down some more, to my answer. The problem is already solved.

Comment: The actual copy sequence is also a bit odd. The `Exists` is superfluous, and I'm not sure why it does `Copy` and `Delete` instead of just `Move`. Again, none of this explains why the file is locked, though.

Comment: Ok, I read it over again, and read Hans' answer, so now I'm starting to understand. Clearly I'm a bit slow. The problem seems to be that they're starting a thread prematurely. The best solution is not to add events or semaphores, but to delay starting the thread. Alternately, rather than requiring communication, the thread can retry on failure, with a suitable delay to avoid slamming. Better?

Comment: @Steven, No, the whole issue was that the Semaphores were setup wrong. For the rest the design is OK, and could make sense depending on what else goes on.

Comment: @Henk: Arguably, this would be a place for `Monitor.Pulse`.

Comment: @Steven: No, that would be hard to get right. A Pulse can easily be missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the Semaphore wrong. Try : `new Semaphore(0, 1);`

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx).

And a WaitEvent is probably easier and more appropriate for this task.

The 2 code changes would be:

```
//Semaphore readyToWrite=new Semaphore(1, 1);
var readyToWrite = new ManualResetEvent(false);

//readyToWrite.Release();
readyToWrite.Set();
```

Also, setting the Priority is usually a bad idea. You're not going to gain anything here (it's an I/O thread), so best leave it.

Comment: +1, Yup.  Starting a thread, then waiting for it is a waste of resources too.  Setting the priority higher doesn't buy a faster hard disk.

Comment: @Hans: agree with the Priority, I'll add that. For the rest I think this is an excerpt so I'm not sure if it is a bad design.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that was simple.  My distilled code had a bug, figures.